# Communicating between ROS and VB

Tags: ros, integration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Howdy,

We have a piece of hardware that, for reasons beyond comprehension, only has Visual Basic .net or C# drivers.  Assuming we can wrap the hardware drivers into Linux, we are still unsure of how we can get ROS to communicate with the VB process.

Does ROS have some kind of support for running VB programs, or is there some way to wrap a VB program into a C++ program?  As a worst case, we'll probably just end up calling the program every time we need it in a node, shutting it down, and doing it all over again, but it'd be great if there were a better option.

Oh and the drivers use a proprietary protocol, so there is no way for us to just re-write the driver in C++ for Linux :-(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32202/communicating-between-ros-and-vb/) by [mstacho](https://answers.ros.org/users/2211/mstacho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if you could use it, but apparently there is now [roscs](http://ros.org/wiki/roscs), so c# is an option. Mono on Linux only apparently, so it would depend on what exactly these 'drivers' do.

Another option might be to use the interop facilities in vb.net or c# to call into a c++ dll that handles the ROS integration (see [streamvis](http://code.google.com/p/streamvis/source/browse/trunk/Source/Wrappers/streamvis-wrappers-ros) for an example and [fuerte/Installation/Windows](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Windows) on how to install the necessary bits on Windows).

Btw: proprietary protocols are not necessarily a problem; it will 'just' require  reverse engineering, hard work and (lots of) time.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [daveayyyy](https://answers.ros.org/users/11371/daveayyyy/) on 2014-01-28**:
Did that work for you? Any code or tips you might share?

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2014-01-29**:
@daveayyyy: I haven't used this myself. @mstacho needed some options, so I listed some.

**Comment by [daveayyyy](https://answers.ros.org/users/11371/daveayyyy/) on 2014-01-29**:
Thanks. FWIW I tried dropping the streamvis DLL's into Unity, and it got as far as an internal compiler error it Data.Ros. So some type of incompatibility there. It ate up the rest of it though, so it might be a way to go.